# Problem with using variable out of a function

Tags: python, function, class, variables, self

I've got problem with this code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(300300)

(n,m) = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
G = [[] for _ in range(n+1)] 
odwiedzony = [False for _ in range(n+1)] 
odwiedzonyPonownie = [False for _ in range(n+1)]

for i in range(m):
    (a, b) = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    G[a].append(b)
    G[b].append(a)

#global op

def dfs(v):
    #op = 0
    odwiedzony[v] = True
    for sąsiad in G[v]:
        if odwiedzony[sąsiad] == True and odwiedzonyPonownie[sąsiad] == False:
            odwiedzonyPonownie[sąsiad] = True
            print("tak")
            op += 1
            print(op)
            #print("op")
        elif sąsiad == v:
            print("V = sąsiad")
            #op = n
        else :
            dfs(sąsiad)

dfs(G[1][0])
if op/2 >= n :
    print("niedrzewo")
else:
    print("drzewo")
```

Because I need to use variable "op" to check if "op" is bigger than "N". But I can't use variable "op" - I need to addition it.
So I decided to use classes to fix that problem, I tried do something like this:

```
    import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(300300)

(n,m) = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
G = [[] for _ in range(n+1)] 
odwiedzony = [False for _ in range(n+1)] 
odwiedzonyPonownie = [False for _ in range(n+1)]

for i in range(m):
    (a, b) = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    G[a].append(b)
    G[b].append(a)

class cus():
    def __init__(self): 
        self.op = 0

    def dfs(self,v):
        odwiedzony[v] = True
        for sąsiad in G[v]:
            if odwiedzony[sąsiad] == True and odwiedzonyPonownie[sąsiad] == False:
                odwiedzonyPonownie[sąsiad] = True
                print("tak")
                self.op += 1
                print(self.op)
            elif sąsiad == v:
                print("V = sąsiad")
                self.op = n
            else :
                dfs(sąsiad)

c = cus()
c.dfs(G[1][0])
if c.op/2 >= n :
    print("niedrzewo")
else:
    print("drzewo")
But I have this mistake:
```

File "path", line 17
self.op = 0
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
Please help!!! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you are mixing tabs and spaces for **indentation** in your code, specifically on line 17 where you set `self.op = 0`.

Python is very sensitive when it comes to indentation and it is highly recommended to use spaces only.

My guess is, your editor switched from spaces to tabs or the other way round, or you have used different editors to edit the same file.